# Prove if X is an orthonormal frame then so is Y

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isometry

I'm trying to prove that if $Y_1, Y_2 : P → V$ is an orthonormal frame with respect to $g$, then so is $X_1, X_2 : P → V$
defined by $X_i(F(p)) = F'(p)(Y_ i(p))$.

It is given that $F : P → P$ is an isometry, from the Riemannian chart $(P,g)$ back to itself. So $F∗g = g$.

How can I prove $X_1, X_2 : P → V$ is also an orthonormal frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p \in P$ we have $g(F(p))(X_i(F(p)),X_j(F(p))) = g(F(p))(F'(p)(Y_i(p)),F'(p)(Y_j(p)))$. Now, you need to apply the definition of the pull-back together with the fact that $F_*g = g.$

Comment: Is it then correct that I get $g(p)(Y_i(p),Y_j(p))$  as the outcome? Is this then the conclusion that  $X_i$ is also an orthonormal basis?

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't do the full computation, but you know that $g(p)(Y_i(p),Y_j(p)) = \delta_{ij}$, since $Y_i$ were an orthonormal frame. The conclusion is then that the $X_i$ are also an orthonormal frame.